# XSS difficult exploitation

Tags: xss, code-injection

I want to inject JavaScript into webpage in order to do an XSS. The page is made with aspx. This webpage contains an XSS filter which replaces angle brackets `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`. For example, if I POST:

```
<script>alert("Hi");</script>
```

I receive `&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;Hi&quot;);&lt;/script&gt;` and the script is never executed.

I have already tried to encode it: I tried Xenotix but with no success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Some sites are simply not vulnerable to XSS, because they do the filtering you describe.

Comment: they filter juste angle brackets , in the rendering of webpage you can see the brackets but in the source &lt; et &gt; and then the script is never executed :(

Comment: it not filter alert and the others javascript keywords it filter just angle brackets and semicolon and quotes

Comment: @user2679084 Yes. That's how you protect yourself from XSS.

Comment: without the angle brackets and quotes, it's just text. You interpret it as code, but from the POV of the computer, it's text.

Comment: I have thought this also depended on the browsers and <script> alert ("Hi") </ script> could execute somewhere

Comment: No, `&gt;` is not the same as `>` for a computer.

Comment: If they accept user input into an attribute XSS is still possible.